# How to respond to git clone command using NGIT

Tags: git, jgit, ngit, smart-http

Using NGit (or even JGit since it's a port) does anyone know how to respond to the Git clone command over Smart HTTP? What would the sample code look like?

I can't find any references or documentation which describes this.

I'm trying to create a .NET GIT server to handle simple clone, push and pull requests.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.GitServlet` to handle fetch and push requests over Smart HTTP.

The specific servlet that handles Smart fetch is the [UploadPackServlet](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.http.server/src/org/eclipse/jgit/http/server/UploadPackServlet.java#L80).

There is a [SimpleHttpServer](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.junit.http/src/org/eclipse/jgit/junit/http/SimpleHttpServer.java) class which is an example Smart HTTP enabled server in the org.eclipse.jgit.junit.http project.

Answer (score 0):

See my fork of GitAspx at https://github.com/linquize/git-dot-aspx

Recently it supports NGit as backend, as the original GitSharp is out of date and buggy
Make sure you host it in IIS. Development server does not support http 1.1